# Linux C++ write string to COM port, read back response?

Tags: c++, linux, string, serial-port, communication

I am trying to write to the /dev/ttyACM0 port. In the command line shell I can write the string ":35\n" to the sensor I have plugged in to that port, and via putty listening on the port I can see it responds and gives me the data I am asking for (compass data).

I want to write a driver in C++ that writes this string to that port and reads in the response returned. I have looked online but have been unsuccessful in writing this. I feel like it should be an easy task. I wouldn't think writing to the ttyACM port would be any different than writing to a ttyCOM or ttyS port. Can anyone give me an example of this? I wouldn't think it'd be more than 5 lines of code.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, five lines of code:

```
#include <fstream>
std::fstream file("/dev/ttyACM0");
file << ":35" << std::endl; // endl does flush, which may be important
std::string response;
file >> response;
```

Comment: I had to use `stty` to disable echoing from PC back to the serial device (which got confused by this echo). This could be accomplished by `<termios.h>` `tcsetattr()`, but `fstream` intentionally provides no access to the underlying file descriptor. https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/5535937/Re-Using-fstream-with-USB-Serial-Port